# Error in Derivation of Tsiolkovsky Rocket Equation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, rocket-science

Can someone point out where the error is in the following derivation of the Tsiolkovsky rocket equation? According to the Newton's second law combined with his third law, we know that the *net external* force on any system is equal to the time derivative of the net translational momentum vector of that system:
$$\sum{\vec{F}}_{ext}=\frac{d\vec{p}_{sys}}{dt}$$
In this case, our system consists of a rocket with all of its initial fuel/propellant (one should view the words "rocket" and "fuel" as distinct objects, i.e. $\{x\in{\mathbb{R}^3:x\in\operatorname{rocket}}\}\cap\{x\in{\mathbb{R}^3:x\in{\operatorname{fuel}}\}}=\emptyset$). Next, use the fundamental limit definition of the derivative:
$$\frac{d\vec{p}_{sys}}{dt}(t)=\lim_{\Delta{t}\rightarrow{0}}\frac{\vec{p}_{sys}(t+\Delta{t})-\vec{p}_{sys}(t)}{\Delta{t}}$$
Now I define some important functions: let $m_{up}(t)$ be the mass of all *upward-moving* particles in the rocket-fuel system at time $t$. Note that the phrase "*upward-moving*" is with respect to the Earth/ground frame of reference, which is assumed to be inertial so that Newton's laws as "packed" into the first equation are actually valid. To get more intuition for the $m_{up}$ function defined above, if at $t=0$ the rocket with *all* its unused, initial fuel lifts off, then $m_{up}(0)=m_{rocket}+m_{fuel}$. But if by the time $t=T$ the rocket has ejected all of its initial fuel in the form of rocket exhaust, then $m_{up}(T)=m_{rocket}$, because the rest of the system's initial mass, namely all of its initial fuel, is no longer *travelling upwards*, and therefore doesn't get counted by the function. Next, define the vector-valued function $\vec{v}_{up}(t)$ which reports the velocity vector of the rocket at time $t$ relative to the Earth/ground frame of reference. For example, $\vec{v}_{up}(0)=\vec{0}$. Finally, define $\vec{u}$ to be the velocity vector of the ejected fuel/exhaust *relative to the rocket* (and we make the assumption that the every single exhaust particle travels at a constant (downward) velocity relative to the rocket, so that $d\vec{u}/dt=\vec{0}$). One more thing I will note is that it arises naturally from our function definitions that the velocity of the fuel/exhaust *relative to the Earth/ground frame of reference* is given by $\vec{u}+\vec{v}_{up}(t)$. Now then, we can compile the following expressions for the net translational momentum vector of the rocket-fuel system at times $t$ and $t+\Delta{t}$:
$$\vec{p}_{sys}(t+\Delta{t})=m_{up}(t+\Delta{t})\vec{v}_{up}(t+\Delta{t})+\biggr(m_{up}(0)-m_{up}(t+\Delta{t})\biggr)\biggr(\vec{u}+\vec{v}_{up}(t+\Delta{t})\biggr)$$
$$\vec{p}_{sys}(t)=m_{up}(t)\vec{v}_{up}(t)+\biggr(m_{up}(0)-m_{up}(t)\biggr)\biggr(\vec{u}+\vec{v}_{up}(t)\biggr)$$
Inserting these expressions into the earlier limit and applying limit laws yields:
$$\frac{d\vec{p}_{sys}}{dt}(t)=\lim_{\Delta{t}\rightarrow{0}}m_{up}(0)\frac{\vec{v}_{up}(t+\Delta{t})-\vec{v}_{up}(t)}{\Delta{t}}-\lim_{\Delta{t}\rightarrow{0}}\vec{u}\frac{m_{up}(t+\Delta{t})-m_{up}(t)}{\Delta{t}}=m_{up}(0)\frac{d\vec{v}_{up}}{dt}(t)-\vec{u}\frac{dm_{up}}{dt}(t)$$
From here, it would be nice if $m_{up}(0)$ was replaced with $m_{up}(t)$, since that would permit the appearance of the natural log function that appears in the ideal form of the rocket equation where $\sum{\vec{F}}_{ext}=\frac{d\vec{p}_{sys}}{dt}=\vec{0}$, but unfortunately that's not the case here, so what is my error?

Comment: You can't write momentum of ejected gases as their total mass times single velocity $\vec{u} + \vec{v}_{up}(t)$. Velocity of an ejected gas element depends on time it was ejected so there is no single common velocity.

Comment: @JánLalinský Can you suggest a more appropriate modified expression then for the net translational momentum of all the ejected gases/exhaust as a function of time?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think it is a good starting point for understanding the rocket equation. Here it is: $\int_0^t - (\mathbf u + \mathbf v(t')) \frac{dm}{dt'}dt'$ where $m$ is mass of the rocket.

Comment: It is based on the integral version of the rocket equation $m\frac{d \mathbf v}{dt} = \frac{dm}{dt} \mathbf u$.

Comment: $\mathbf u$ is velocity of the exhaust gases in the frame of the rocket (when they leave and stop pushing the rocket).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Derivation of Tsiolkovsky rocket equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/551271/derivation-of-tsiolkovsky-rocket-equation)